# How to use offset after obtaining reference cell using indexOf in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, offset, indexof

I've written a script to find a match of a given cell via for loop variable (it works great).  When logged out, it provides the position 11.0 in the searched column of data.  What I then want to do is uncheck a checkbox that is offset by (0,-5) from that referenced cell.  When I try to use offset, I get the TypeError:  offset is not a function.  How do I accomplish this?

Below is the script I've written to get to where I am stuck.  What I am doing is checking a box on Sheet2,  which is on the same row for a given product.  The row on which the product and its checkbox reside will not always be the same (could be row 5, could be row 12).  Once I check the box, the script determines what the name of the product is (in this case, Product L), and then looks for its match via indexOf on Sheet1.  IndexOf finds the location on Sheet1 (in this case, 11.0, which is row 13, col 10).  There is a corresponding checkbox on Sheet1 row 13 in column 5 which then needs to be unchecked.  And that is where I am stuck.  The sheet is dynamic, and the rows for checkboxes and corresponding products will constantly be changing.

```
function findText() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lr = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var lookupRangeArray = sheet1.getRange(3,10,lr,1).getValues();
  var newRange = lookupRangeArray.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });    
 for (var i=0; i <= lr; i++){
   var checkboxRange = sheet2.getRange(i+1,2);
   var checkboxStatus = checkboxRange.getValue();
  if(checkboxStatus == true){  
   var text = checkboxRange.offset(0, 2).getValue();
   Logger.log(text);
   var position = newRange.indexOf(text);
   Logger.log(position)
   position.offset(0,-5).setValue(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

### You need to retrieve the cell to offset

You can do it e.g. by specifying the row and column position of the cell reference or its `A1` notation.

Sample

```
var row=1;
var column = 11;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getRange(row, column);
var newCell = cell.offset(0, -5);
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick response.  So, the position that indexOf provides will always be changing as the sheet is dynamic.  EG - position 11.0 will change to 1.0, 5.0, 4.0,etc.  So does the retrieval need to be accomplished via a loop?

Comment: It would be easier to understand your issue if you could provide your code.

Comment: Yeah.  I realized that, and was adding it to my question as you were probably requesting it.

Comment: Being new the the scripting thing (probably painfully obvious), I was hoping that simply adding   "position.offset(0,-5).setValue(false)" would do what I'm looking for.  Aaaaand no.  Just get TypeError: offset is not a function.

Comment: In your case implement inside your loop after `var position = newRange.indexOf(text);`: `var column =  position + ; `. With this you can define `cell` and `cell.offset(0, -5).setValue(false)` - all inside the same `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks!  Man, I wish I was more adept at this.  I'm guessing that there needs to be something after the "+", because if I put in "var column = position + ;" as it's own line, I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' .

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant `position + 3` (because 3 is the first row of your `lookupRangeArray`)

Comment: Again, thank you.  Would it be possible to use var position as the row in getRange()?  EG - var cell = sheet2.getRange(position, 10);   and then write "cell.offset(0,-5).setValue(false);  ?

Comment: It worked!!!  Wrote "var cell = sheet2.getRange(position + 3, 10), then cell.offset(0,-5).setValue(false).  Thank you SOOOOO much for helping me work through this!!!  Needless to say, I have been stumped for a while.